# Is there a benefit to multiple interceptors on one satellite?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Besides the obvious benefit of having an interceptor as a back up in case one is damaged or destroyed, is there a bonus to having two interceptors on one satellite to protect/shoot down ufos?

I thought I saw some screenshots of two interceptors against one ufo.  But early on, a ufo appears and one interceptor sorties.  It shoots it down, but I had two in that area.  Why did only one sortie?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've seen two benefits:

1. Possible to continue a failed attack on a UFO. If the first interceptor dies or aborts you can launch a second interceptor - unlike David Burton I haven't had any problems doing this.
2. Possible to equip different weapons for different targets, such as high power weapons for larger UFOs. I'm uncertain if this alters what can be recovered on the ground (ie overkill = less items), but I wouldn't be surprised if it does.

Comment: Ion weapons will preserve everything on an UFO. They will also down any ship on normal difficulty on a Firestorm without one-use items, save for the battleship, for which you will need to use 1 evade. Good deal, especially since battleships have a unique and very useful system on board.

Comment: Although you only need one of said unique system to research for the unlocks. But yes, you definitely want that ship as intact as possible for sweet sweet loot.

Answer (score 5):

I have found no bonus to dispatching two, but a fatal bug.

I recently dispatched a second interceptor on an airborne UFO by clicking on the UFO graphic and selecting my second interceptor. Do Not Do This. I downed the UFO with first craft, then Skyranger came in and soldiers cleared crash site. On mission complete, that second interceptor did not return to hangar, but drifted to north pole lol and the game went to the geoscape display, but in a zoomed in fashion. I could not esc out or do anything to exit this problem. Closing program with task manager does work.

Comment: The same thing happened to me... on ironman mode....

Comment: This in response to the game bugging out over 2 interceptors and flying to north pole