# How to scramble multiple interceptors in XCOM EU

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is it possible to scramble multiple interceptors in XCOM: Enemy Unknown?

As soon as I click on 1 it is launched, I would like to scramble all of them together.

Answer (score 16):

It is not possible to engage Alien UFOs with more than one craft at a time.

Therefore, the best (read: only) possible course of action is to launch Interceptors individually, engaging in a series of 1 on 1 dogfights.

There is nothing stopping you from pulling back before your interceptors lose, however, and as an added bonus, the UFO will still be damaged when your next interceptor launches and makes it into range. (You do have quite a good bit of time to intercept, even multiple times)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot scramble multiple interceptors.  In fact if you somehow glitch the game and scramble 2, you'll run into a [nasty bug](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/87306/3917).

Comment: Ah I ran into that bug and I did not understand why it happened ! lol

Comment: That was the reason I was going to ask the same questions. How did they achieve that. I want to do that also (at least when the bug is fixed).